# Regression of Y on different quantiles of X in Stata

Tags: regression, stata, quantiles

I have data on a dependent variable y and an explanatory one, x, and want to find out if there is a non-linear relationship between theses by running regressions where the data is divided in quartiles from the lowest to the highest value of x. So for example, what is the slope of x when x lies in the first quartile, say between 0 and 4 compared to when in the second, say between 4 and 10? I´m confused on how to accomplish this in Stata. Any help would be much appreciated!

Thanks in advance

Oscar

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a highly problematic statistical practice.  Besides greatly reducing power, it actually assumes a very strange relationship between X and Y.  Suppose that X was linearly related to Y and that X did not have a uniform distribution.  The the proposed approach would come up with a nonlinear relationship.  It does not make sense for X to relate to Y by the shape of the marginal distribution of X.  A better approach would be to fit a regression spline in the original X.  You are also assuming that slope changes occur at certain percentiles of X which is hard to believe.

Comment: Frank, in your example with non-uniformly distributed X - if Oscar cuts X in subranges of equal width instead of cutting it at quartiles, will he still end up with a nonlinear relationship?

Comment: Let me back up.  The problem as originally stated can be dealt with using linear splines with intercepts restricted so that the segments meet at the join points (quartiles).  Handouts at http://biostat.mc.vanderbilt.edu/rms show how [in the R rms package you can use the lsp function].  But there is no reason to assume that quartiles are where slope changes should happen, and cubic splines are likely to fit better, without having elbows in the fit.

Comment: Why not use LOESS? Are there advantages of regression spline smoothing over LOESS?

Comment: Loess would be an excellent choice here, much like regression splines.  Both assume smoothness.  Regression splines are easier to deal with to get confidence bands and hypothesis tests, and to generalize to the multivariable case.

Comment: @Frank Harrell Thanks very much for the input! I'm trying out the b-spline function suggested above. What I actually have is data on tariffs as an explanatory variable and a proxy for customs evasion as the dependent variable. I wanted to know if there could be some fixed cost to evading customs so that at low tariffs evasion would be small (falt slope) and once tariffs get bigger one would see more of an effect.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming you work with Stata 11 or above, so that you can easily use factor variables, you probably would want to do something like

```
    sysuse auto, clear
    xtile qprice = price , nq(4)
    reg mpg c.price##i.qprice
    testparm i(2/4).qprice#c.price i(2/4).qprice
```

If this solution is unclear, comment on it, I'll expand the explanation.

Comment: `bsline ..., p(1) ... ` is a nice shortcut:  See http://data.princeton.edu/eco572/smoothing2.html

Comment: `bspline`, you mean. Yes, that certainly is an alternative. Frank Harrell mentions it in the other branch. I would personally stay with the cubic default though.